# A calculation error made a rebus

Tags: rebus

What does this little rebus mean?

> <s>14</s>   0

Is fourteen wrong or what?

EDIT:

OK, there have been way too many answers, only a few having some reasonable match with the rebus. To avoid another flood of not-so-nicely-matched answers, here is a

**Hint**:

> The "strike-through" (or whatever it's called), is not pronounced *per se*. It adds meaning. The rest is pronounced.

**Another hint**:

> <s>hit</s>   0, Jack

Comment: What language is it supposed to be solved in?

Comment: @Decypher, In English. Note that, just like many rebuses, it translates into a common idiom.

Comment: score 14:0 (possible in Rugby) but not a CEI

Comment: This is kiiiiiiiiilling me.

Comment: Are the additional spaces added for better readability, or do they have a meaning? (The space before the `1`; after the `4`; and the additional space between the strike-through 14 and `0`.)

Comment: @Kevin, Just for readability. The stroke above 14 was not visible enough.

Comment: @fffred well that chances a lot :) back to thinking!

Comment: There is a saying in Romanian that translates literally to "It hurts in my fourteen". It means "I don't give a ... damn". So this could be it. since "giving a damn" could mean "zero damns given". (it involves 14 and zero).

Comment: if the score was on the 0 instead it would be 'one for all'

Comment: Would a certain pronunciation of '0' be the key here?

Comment: If the meaning of the strikethrough is pronounced, then the strikethrough is pronounced

Comment: Is there any significance to the "calculation" part of the rebus? Is it a coincidence that the numbers 0,1, and 4 could all look somewhat like letters when typed into a calculator and viewed upside down('O'=0, 'b'=4, 'i'/'L'=1)?

Comment: @Matthew0898 I would say that 4=h when viewed upside-down in a calculator...

Comment: @question_asker, whether the meaning is pronounced or not is a tricky and misleading issue. It makes sense as a whole, and I really believe the rebus is really a rebus.

Comment: @fffred You can't say it's not pronounced to justify turning down an answer that interprets it as "not" if you're going to accept an answer that interprets it as any other word.

Comment: @Matthew0898, there is no such visual trick. It is just a plain rebus. Find a clever pronunciation, stretch it a tiny bit, and find an idiom.

Comment: @question_asker, you're right, but I did not expect such close matches. I'm trying now to find a completion to the rebus that would rule out a few answers.

Comment: Argh ! I definitely got it, but can't post an answer because the question is protected :(

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about

> One for the road

because

> you zero out one-four, or you have "one four zeroed". Stretching the pronunciation a bit (or using the Spanish theta), you get "one for the road"(or "one for ze road").

Comment: Phew, that took many answers, but well done !

Comment: Did anyone else say this like N. Gin from Crash Team Racing?.... No, just me?! ok then.

Comment: In Spanish, "z" sounds as the first sound of "thick". I believe your comment  should in fact refer to the German-ish pronounciation of "the" ("ze"), which you mention later on.

Answer (score 16):

Here's my guess:

> Not one for small talk. Strikethrough 14 is not one for, and 0 is small talk. Kind of a stretch though

Comment: Indeed, too much of a stretch, but there is some sort of evolution in the right direction.

Answer (score 13):

My first answer so hopefully I am doing the spoiler hiding thing correctly...

> Not number one for nothing

Comment: oh wow, I think this is it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wasn't it, nice job

Comment: Nope, sorry guys :) The hint indicates that the strike-through is not pronounced. Here, is it pronounced as "Not". Maybe I should make the puzzle a little more specific ...

Comment: @fffred Well, I mean, this answer doesn't work because then it should be "Not number fourteen for nothing" ;)

Comment: @insane, it works if you pronounce 14 as "number one for"

Comment: @fffred Ohhh lol

Answer (score 7):

I think it translates to

> Not for teens

Comment: I thought this, but how does the 0 fit in?

Comment: Incorrect answer, but nice attempt with the pronunciation.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an attempt to not use the strike-through as "not":

> Have one for free

This potentially works because

> we can imagine the line "halving" the fourteen -> "halve" -> "have" and then 0 could represent nothing which when talking about money would be equivalent to free.

Answer (score 5):

I think it means

> Always be positive

Reasoning:

> Original equation was $7 - 7$
>  Being positive and ignoring negatives, you made a calculation error and answered $14 (7 + 7)$ instead of $0$

Comment: Interesting idea, but does not fit the rebus well enough.

Comment: There is no information regarding the original equation.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to various answers but

> You can't get something for nothing

Because:

> 1 = something 
>  4 = for 
>  0 = nothing 
>  strikethrough = if these are the answer to an equation you would 'get' 14, and the strikethrough show that we can't get it

Answer (score 4):

A possibility:

> Not one for naught

Comment: That would be the first good (but coincidental) match. However, I never heard this idiom before ... Is it really used?

Comment: I think the actual idiom I was thinking of is Not for Naught.

Comment: Or maybe "All for naught" ?

Comment: "not for nothing" is common, so I imagine someone probably says "not for naught", but this rebus doesn't spell that

Answer (score 4):

Guessing:

> Take one for the team

Reason:

> When editing a document, " <s>14</s> " would 'take out' "14".
>  The "0" might be visually representative of a huddled sports team.

Answer (score 2):

I have to try this one!

> **Don't count your chickens before the eggs have hatched** : you had 14 eggs that haven't hatched yet, so you counted 14 chickens, but then they all turned out to be ones without chickens, and you actually have 0 chickens!

Comment: Nice try ! +1 for the idea, but 14 is not any random thing.

Comment: Argh, time to search again !

Answer (score 2):

Probably very far'fetched, but:

> Two (male) teens without girlfriends

because:

> <s>14</s>  => Four teens split / divided => Two teens
>
>
>  I tried to come up with a suitable verb for the `0`..
>
>  I interpreted the `0` as an `O` because:
>  ["The modern numerical digit 0 is usually written as a circle or ellipse. Traditionally, many print typefaces made the capital letter O more rounded than the narrower, elliptical digit 0. Typewriters originally made no distinction in shape between O and 0; some models did not even have a separate key for the digit 0. The distinction came into prominence on modern character displays."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(number)#Symbols_and_representations)
>
>  And found the following meaning for O'ing:
>  ["If you've ever heard of the term "dinks" meaning "double income, no kids" , Oing is for males that have a decent paying job and are in the age range of 16-25 meaning "One income, No girlfriend". It stops at 25 because if you have no girl at 25, you're a loser."](http://nl.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=O%27ing&defid=6322596)
>
>  The age-range of 16-25 also fits the term teens.

Comment: Man, I'm really impressed by all the ideas here, but this is not correct. I would not have replaced 0 by O just for fun anyway. The characters are chosen for good reasons.

Comment: @fffred Well, two teens [zeroing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroing_(trade)) didn't made much sense, so I had to look in another direction. :)

Answer (score 2):

So, how about:

> Not one for pi(e)? The O being a circle, so related to pi...

Comment: Well, nice try, but still not quite there yet. A zero is *not* a circle, really.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

> **Hold the fort** : maybe it's related to the word **fort**, as '**fort**night' means '**14** days'

Comment: Still not the answer ... :)

Answer (score 1):

My long shot:

> A strike for nothing

Comment: I am unaware of this idiom. But anyway, what would the *1* be there for?

Comment: @fffred "A" and "One" are interchangeable. :)

Answer (score 1):

New try

> One for All

because

> It's not one for nothing because there is a strikethrough, so the opposite would be one for all.

Comment: Still incorrect. Try again :) With your explanation, "Not for" would have been simply a 4 stroke out.